# Can't query MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to query a database using php5.6, I can't get this query to work, the error seems to be with

```
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) OR die('nope'. mysql_error());
```

This is my query php file:

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM USERS";

$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) OR die('nope'. mysql_error());

    if ($response){
        echo 'Query successful!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error - query unsuccessful';
    }

?>
```

This is my db connection file:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$DB_User = 'user';
$DB_Passwd = 'pass';
$DB_Host = 'localhost';
$DB_Name = 'myDB';

$dbc = mysqli_connect($DB_Host,$DB_User,$DB_Passwd,$DB_Name);
if (!$dbc) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```

I've updated the files to all use mysqli and removed the @, but it's still not connecting or showing errors, still just throwing a 500. I'm not sure where to go from here...

Comment: What error? You're suppressing it with an `@`, which you should never do.

Comment: Use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect`, and you should not mute errors with `@`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: ooohh.. ok thanks. so is it just mysql_connect ----> mysqli_connect or anywhere mysql_anything would be?

Answer (score 1):

in this line you should use `mysqli_connect()` instead of `mysql_connect()`

```
$dbc = @mysql_connect($DB_Host,$DB_User,$DB_Passwd,$DB_Name)
```

and in case of @mysql_connect() your syntax will be like this

```
$dbc = @mysql_connect($DB_Host,$DB_User,$DB_Passwd);
if (!$dbc) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $dbc);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use database : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

// NOTE THAT

mysql is deprecated since 5.5 and deleted in php 7
so it is not recommended to use it

Comment: so any place 'mysql' is is replaced with 'mysqli'?

Comment: @NickFusaro that's right , with the valid syntax of mysqli . check php documentatons for that .